# Find differences between matrix columns and vector

Tags: r, apply

I have this setup: an m-vector and an m-by-n matrix.

```
v = c(1,2,3)
M = matrix(c(1,2,3,1,2,4), nrow = 3)
```

I want to create a matrix `A` whose values `A[i,j]` are 0 if `M[i,j] == v[i]` and 1 otherwise. So it should locate the places where the columns of M differ from v.

I've been trying stuff like:

```
A = apply(M, 2, != v)
```

But that gives

```
Error: unexpected '!=' in "apply(M, 2, !="
```

Comment: `FUN='!='`  But you can do without `apply()`: `M!=v` using the recycling rule

Comment: @jogo Super. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A <- apply(M, 2, FUN='!=', y=v)
```

But you can do without `apply()`:

```
A <- (M!=v)
```

using the recycling rule